# Update news feed in real time based on search in JS

Tags: javascript, html, api, search, toggle

I have been learning JS over the last 2 weeks and am trying to build a news app using the Guardian's Api. I have managed to get the images, links and headlines pulling in, but I am struggling with getting the search functionality working. I want it to work so the page instantly updates as soon as you start typing. I can see the below is 'working' in the console but I can't figure out how to display it effectively on the page.

I have tried creating a new array for 'searched for articles' but this was too long winded and did not return a real time updated feed whilst typing.

I have tried 'toggling' the h1 (headline) elements of the articles, but kept getting 'not a function' errors.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure of the best approach here.

[image: console log of news feed]

`VIEW CLASS`

```
class ArticlesView {
  constructor(model, api) {
    this.model = model;
    this.api = api;
    this.articlesFromModel = this.model.getArticles();
    this.newsFeed = document.querySelector("#news-feed");
    this.clearFeedBtn = document.querySelector("#clear-feed-button");
    this.refreshBtn = document.querySelector("#refresh-button");
    this.searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");
    this.allHeadlines = [document.querySelectorAll("h1")];
    this.clearFeedBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.clearFeed();
    });
    this.searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
      this.articlesFromModel.forEach((article) => {
        const searchInput = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        const isVisible = article.webTitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
        if (!isVisible) { 
**        // not sure what to do here
**        }
        console.log(searchInput);
        console.log(article.webTitle);
        console.log(isVisible);
      });
    });
  }

  displayArticlesFromApi() {
    this.api.loadArticles(
      (repoData) => {
        this.model.addArticle(repoData.response.results);
        this.displayArticles();
      },
      () => {
        this.displayError();
      }
    );
  }

  displayArticles() {
    this.articlesFromModel.forEach((article) => {
      this.addImage(article);
      this.addHeadline(article);
    });
  }

  addHeadline(article) {
    const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.className = "news-title";
    h1.innerText = article.webTitle;
    h1.onclick = () => {
      window.location.href = article.webUrl;
    };
    this.newsFeed.append(h1);
  }

  addImage(article) {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.className = "news-image";
    img.setAttribute("id", article.id);
    img.src = article.fields.thumbnail;
    img.onclick = () => {
      window.location.href = article.webUrl;
    };
    this.newsFeed.append(img);
  }

  displayError() {
    let errorMessage = document.createElement("div");
    errorMessage.className = "error";
    errorMessage.textContent = "Oops, something went wrong!";
    this.newFeed.append(errorMessage);
  }

  clearFeed() {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll("img.news-image");
    images.forEach((element) => {
      element.remove();
    });
    const headlines = document.querySelectorAll("h1.news-title");
    headlines.forEach((element) => {
      element.remove();
    });
  }
}

module.exports = ArticlesView;
```

`MODEL CLASS`

```
class ArticlesModel {
  constructor() {
    this.articles = [];
  }

  getArticles() {
    return this.articles;
  }

  addArticle(article) {
    article.forEach((a) => {
      this.articles.push(a);
    });
  }

  reset() {
    this.articles = [];
  }
}

module.exports = ArticlesModel;
```

`API CLASS`

```
class GuardianApi {
  constructor() {
    this.apiURL = `https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=${apikey}&show-fields=thumbnail`;
  }
  loadArticles(callback) {
    fetch(this.apiURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        callback(data);
      });
  }
}

module.exports = GuardianApi;
```

`INDEX.js`

```
console.log("the app is running");
const ArticlesModel = require("./src/ArticlesModel.js");
const ArticlesView = require("./src/ArticlesView.js");
const GuardianApi = require("./src/GuardianApi.js");

const client = new GuardianApi();
const model = new ArticlesModel();
const view = new ArticlesView(model, client);

view.displayArticlesFromApi();
```

`HTML FILE`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title> Your Daily News Feed</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>News Feed</h1>

        <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="e.g. Football...">
      
      <br><br>
      <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh Page</button> <button id="clear-feed-button">Clear Feed</button>
      
      <br> <br>

      <div id="news-feed">

      </div>
   </body>
   <script src="bundle.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: When you say instantly updates, what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to filter the articles already on the screen and display only those ones that have the keyword that you're searching for, or do you want a fresh search of articles each time the keyword is updated?

Comment: I want it to filter the articles already on the screen. However, if a fresh search each time is a lot more simple then that also works for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a code snippet for your case. You'll need to adjust the line for the api key. For now I've used a key generated for a dummy email. I've also highlighted where the code was changed

The new search function is:

```
this.searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const searchInput = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // Create a filtered copy of articlesFromModel
    const filteredArticles = this.articlesFromModel.filter((article) => {
        return article.webTitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
    });
    this.clearFeed()
    // Display filtered list.
    this.displayArticles(filteredArticles);
});
```

`displayArticles()` has been modified to accept a parameter

```
displayArticles(articles) {
    articles.forEach((article) => {
        this.addImage(article);
        this.addHeadline(article);
  });
}
```

#### Filtering existing articles

```js
class ArticlesView {
  constructor(model, api) {
    this.model = model;
    this.api = api;
    this.articlesFromModel = this.model.getArticles();
    this.newsFeed = document.querySelector("#news-feed");
    this.clearFeedBtn = document.querySelector("#clear-feed-button");
    this.refreshBtn = document.querySelector("#refresh-button");
    this.searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");
    this.allHeadlines = [document.querySelectorAll("h1")];
    this.clearFeedBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.clearFeed();
    });
    // New search function
    this.searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
      const searchInput = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
      // Create a filtered copy of articlesFromModel
      const filteredArticles = this.articlesFromModel.filter((article) => {
        return article.webTitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
      });
      this.clearFeed()
      // Display filtered list.
      this.displayArticles(filteredArticles);
    });
}

displayArticlesFromApi() {
  this.api.loadArticles(
    (repoData) => {
      this.model.addArticle(repoData.response.results);
      // displayArticles() is now being passed an argument
      this.displayArticles(this.articlesFromModel);
    },
    () => {
      this.displayError();
    }
  );
}

// displayArticles() now accepts an argument
displayArticles(articles) {
  articles.forEach((article) => {
    this.addImage(article);
    this.addHeadline(article);
  });
}

addHeadline(article) {
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.className = "news-title";
  h1.innerText = article.webTitle;
  h1.onclick = () => {
    window.location.href = article.webUrl;
  };
  this.newsFeed.append(h1);
}

addImage(article) {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.className = "news-image";
  img.setAttribute("id", article.id);
  img.src = article.fields.thumbnail;
  img.onclick = () => {
    window.location.href = article.webUrl;
  };
  this.newsFeed.append(img);
}

displayError() {
  let errorMessage = document.createElement("div");
  errorMessage.className = "error";
  errorMessage.textContent = "Oops, something went wrong!";
  this.newFeed.append(errorMessage);
}

clearFeed() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img.news-image");
  images.forEach((element) => {
    element.remove();
  });
  const headlines = document.querySelectorAll("h1.news-title");
  headlines.forEach((element) => {
    element.remove();
  });
}
}

class ArticlesModel {
  constructor() {
    this.articles = [];
  }

  getArticles() {
    return this.articles;
  }

  addArticle(article) {
    article.forEach((a) => {
      this.articles.push(a);
    });
  }

  reset() {
    this.articles = [];
  }
}

class GuardianApi {
  constructor() {
    this.apiURL = `https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=bb887d29-f877-4222-96b2-c1e7051bcf71&show-fields=thumbnail`;
  }
  loadArticles(callback) {
    fetch(this.apiURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        callback(data);
      });
  }
}

const client = new GuardianApi();
const model = new ArticlesModel();
const view = new ArticlesView(model, client);

view.displayArticlesFromApi();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title> Your Daily News Feed</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>News Feed</h1>

  <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="e.g. Football...">

  <br><br>
  <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Refresh Page</button> <button id="clear-feed-button">Clear Feed</button>

  <br> <br>

  <div id="news-feed">

  </div>
</body>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Omar. Being a massive rookie I was stuck for hours thinking of all the possible solutions and this is by far the most elegant one I could have thought of.